# How to make request every 2 seconds with angular js and node js?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ajax, httprequest, setinterval

I have a server written with Nodejs that collects data. My client side is written with AngularJS. I need to create http request every two seconds to my server (setInterval) and display updated data. My server running 24/7. Can chrome block my requests if it reaches maximum? Can I implement another way, instead of create request from client side, maybe to push from my server?

Example of some request:

```
var indicesTimer = setInterval(getIndices,2000);
getIndices();


function getIndices(){  
  dataService.getIndices().then(function(res){
    $scope.recentIndeces = res.data;
  });
}
```

Comment: Websocket/Comet/Long Polling are the different options available to do a server push instead of client pull

Answer (score 0):

Check [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) service.

```
  var stop = $interval(function() {
                 // Your code
             }, 100);
```

With your code

```
var indicesTimer = $interval(getIndices,2000);
getIndices();


function getIndices(){  
  dataService.getIndices().then(function(res){
    $scope.recentIndeces = res.data;
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It looks like something I was looking for. I will try this one and get you know

Answer (score 0):

You can use websocket. By using that, your server can notify your client in case something changed in the server side so you don't have to do a polling (polling is what you do when sending request every x seconds). Take a look at socket.io

Answer (score 0):

This is the typically behavior of a heartbeat. Chrome or any other browser does not block requests. 
As long as your `setInterval()` handler doesn't run forever, it won't block other things from eventually running.

Comment: While creating my site and using setInterval - I got this kind of error in chrome console: "net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES" and it means that I created too many requests and chrome started to block it, so that is the reason I posted my question.